# Как считать clobber из таблицы?

Tags: python, oracle

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно считать clobber из таблицы?

```
Cur.execute("select email, html, id from table")
lettter = cur.fetchall()
conn.close()
for i in letter:
    if len(letter) > 0:
        rec = i[0]
        html = i[1].read() #Это CLOB
        id = i[2]
```

Дальше начинаю перебирать и получаю ошибку:

```
Cx.oracle.programmingerror: lob variable no longer valid after subsequent fetch
```

Все работает, если использовать метод fetchone(), но тогда придётся динамически собирать SQL запрос и передавать ему номер строки.

Как быть?

Comment: вы можете привести код где вы непосредственно читаете CLOB's и где закрываете курсор и / или connection

Comment: MaxU, поправил код выше. connection закрывал как в конце всего кода, так и после fetch. Курсор вообще не закрывал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [документации](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lob.html) явно указано не использовать `fetchall()` в том случае если у вас есть CLOB:

> Internally, Oracle uses LOB locators which are allocated based on the
>   cursor array size. Thus, it is important that the data in the LOB
>   object be manipulated before another internal fetch takes place.
>
> The safest way to do this is to use the cursor as an iterator. **In
>   particular, do not use the fetchall() method. The exception “LOB
>   variable no longer valid after subsequent fetch” will be raised** if an
>   attempt to access a LOB variable after a subsequent fetch is detected.

Попробуйте так:

```
cur.execute("select email, html, id from table")
for row in cur:
    ...
```

Comment: Про неиспользовать fetchall читал, но не догадался, что использоваться вместо этого. Попробую, спасибо

Comment: MaxU, Оокей ;-)